# pass table row object from table and edit it using Redx-Form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, redux-thunk, react-router-dom, reducers

I'm trying to pass the table row object to Redux-Form to Edit the object values.

[image]

here some contents of **[ViewStudents.js](https://github.com/kelumKP/student_app/blob/master/src/Components/ViewStudents.js)** file

```
  handleEdit(e, student) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(allActions.editStudents(this.state));
    this.setState({
      firstName: student.firstName,
      lastName: student.lastName
    });
    this.props.history.push("/EditStudents");
  }

  <button  onClick={e => this.handleEdit(e, student)}>Edit</button>


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { students } = state.viewStudents;
  return {
    students
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ViewStudents);
```

here some contents of **[EditStudents.js](https://github.com/kelumKP/student_app/blob/master/src/Components/EditStudents.js)**

[image]

```
      constructor(student) {
        super(student);
        this.state = {
          firstName: student.firstName,
          lastName: student.lastName
        };
      }

      handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        dispatch(allActions.editStudents(this.state));
        this.setState({
          firstName: "",
          lastName: ""
        });
        this.props.history.push("/ViewStudents");
      }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { student } = state.addStudents;
  return {
    initialValues: {
      firstName: state.student.firstName,
      lastName: state.student.lastName
    }
  };
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: "EditForm",
  validate,
  mapStateToProps
})(EditStudents);
```

Problem is, this object values not passing to edit form, though I bind in **mapStateToProps**, **initialValues** and passed this object in **constructor**

how to bind this and pass properly the clicking object in a table row and edit/save that object

Answer (score 0):

Few small issues I can see with this.
You shouldn't use state to select what item you wish to edit. Always think that a user will refresh the page at any item. Therefore you should use React Router Splat to pass a unique value/ID.

http://localhost:3000/EditStudents/1

To do this you need to add a unique id for each student when adding and then use the ID with the route.

```
<Route path="/EditStudents/:studentId" component={EditStudents} />
```

You can then read the ID and load on componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    var {studentId } = props.match.params;
    dispatch( { type: "LOAD_STUDENT", studentId });
}
```

The use of refreshing the state (request, success) has the effect of clearing the data. Therefore any initial state is lost.

Note, you are also using a Service to load in data. 
Really you should be using an async thunk to load data into redux.
You should only get data from and to redux and then use middleware to persist the data.

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

https://codesandbox.io/s/MQnD536Km